# Как сделать, чтобы фигура, движущаяся по траектории SVG, меняла свое положение относительно траектории?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animation, smil

Имеется траектория с `path`. Нужно чтобы эллипс менял свой угол, чтобы перерывать траекторию одинаково по всему пути.

Вот код:`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="41" height="196" viewBox="0 0 41 196">
  <defs>
    <style>

      .cls-2 {
        stroke: #f7d100;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: none;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M39.807,0.686 C22.350,19.430 15.544,48.879 30.187,94.500 C50.898,159.021 23.175,185.666 0.936,196.446 " id="t_path" class="cls-2" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  <!--<mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
    <circle r="7" cx="32" cy="10" fill="black" stroke="green" ></circle> 
                 <animateMotion begin="click"  end="" 
                     dur="5s" repeatCount="3" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
                     <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
                </animateMotion>-->
  <ellipse id="circle2" rx="5" ry="25   " cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato" />

  <animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#circle2"
           dur="1s"
           begin="click"
           fill=#00a82b
           path="M39.807,0.686 C22.350,19.430 15.544,48.879 30.187,94.500 C50.898,159.021 23.175,185.666 0.936,196.4465"
           />     
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решило добавление атрибута rotate в тег amimateMotion

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="41" height="196" viewBox="0 0 41 196">
  <defs>
    <style>

      .cls-2 {
        stroke: #f7d100;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: none;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M39.807,0.686 C22.350,19.430 15.544,48.879 30.187,94.500 C50.898,159.021 23.175,185.666 0.936,196.446 " id="t2_path" class="cls-2" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  <ellipse id="circle2" rx="15" ry="5" cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato" />

  <animateMotion 
           xlink:href="#circle2"
           dur="1s"
           begin="svg2.click"
           fill=#00a82b
           rotate=auto-reverse> 
           <mpath xlink:href="#t2_path">
           </animateMotion>     
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Очень много ошибок и в семантике кода SVG и в масштабировании.
Я покажу основные моменты из-за чего это всё не работало.

Остальное - смотрите работающий код и комментарии.

1. Масштабирование

Красная рамка это граница холста SVG. Траектория движения - жёлтая линия вплотную подходит к границам SVG. Поэтому, при движении красного эллипса он будет выходить на некоторых участках за её границы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно уменьшить размеры эллипса и расширить границы.

Было:

`width="41" height="196" viewBox="0 0 41 196"`

Стало:

`width="50" height="220" viewBox="-5 -5 50 220"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Запуск анимации не сработает, как у вас было -  `begin="click"`

Так как нужно указать объект по которому нужно кликнуть, чтобы запустить анимацию

`begin="svg1.click"` id="svg1" (в шапке svg ) То есть по любому месту на холсте SVG (внутри серой рамки)

`repeatCount="indefinite"`  - бесконечное повторение анимации

`repeatCount="2"` - повторение анимации 2 раза, если параметр не указан, то по умолчанию `repeatCount="1"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="50" height="220" viewBox="-5 -5 50 220" style="border:1px dotted gray;">
  <defs>
    <style>

      .cls-2 {
        stroke: gold;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        fill: none;
      }
    </style>
  </defs> 
  
    <!-- Траектория движения -->
  <path id="t_path" d="M39.807,0.686 C22.350,19.430 15.544,48.879 30.187,94.500 C50.898,159.021 23.175,185.666 0.936,196.446 "  class="cls-2" />
      
 <ellipse id="circle2" rx="5" ry="10" cx="0" cy="0" fill="tomato" >

     <animateMotion
    dur="5s"
    begin="svg1.click"
    repeatCount="indefinite">
        <!-- Путь по которому движется эллипс  -->
         <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
     </animateMotion>  
 </ellipse>    
  
    
</svg>
```

Comment: Вопрос кстати был про поворот...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Спасибо, за улучшение кода и за новую, полезную информацию, но вопрос был в другом. Нужно чтобы данный эллипс поворачивался относительно пути, а не просто смотрел сверху вниз.

Comment: @ИльяЯковлев да не за что.